# entity framework map one model to many table

Tags: entity-framework

I store data in table named by month,such as data201201,data201202 and so on,table is created in the first day of month,all tables have same struct.I design this because each month ten million rows increase and I have only sqlserver standard version so Partition table can not be used.

Before use entity framework,i used sql string to query data,so I can change tablename in sql string by query condition.

Is these any way that I can query related table in Entity Framework?
I have two idea:
1.another table design that can support such big data and minor cost?
2.Intercept ef's query and change table name by query condition,and continue this query,but how and where i can do so?